# Simple keystone correction for video output

Tags: macos

I have a video output to a projector, and due to the way our room is setup, I need to do some keystone correction.

Any idea how I can go about this? I essentially just want to be able to skew my display (as I'm mirroring).

Comment: Keystone corrections are usually done on the projector itself, not on the computer. Is this not possible in your setup?

Comment: unfortunately, no - not available on my projector. I was hoping there was some display skewing software for OS X (since my projector just mirrors my OS X display)